# Action Extension works on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, action

There is an application on iPhone. The Action Extension is used, it works great on the iPhone, but when you add Destination = iPad, the application starts, works, but the extension does not work.

```
Error:
-[_EXSinkLoadOperator loadItemForTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:expectedValueClass:options:] nil expectedValueClass allowing {(
     NSURL,
     NSDictionary
     _EXItemProviderSandboxedResource,
     NSUUID,
     NSDate,
     NSArray,
     NSData,
     NSString,
     NSNumber
     NSError
     UIImage,
     NSValue
)}
```

The error occurs here:

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(typeImage) {
      **itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: typeImage, options: nil) { item, error in**
```

Doesn't work on a real device, works on simulators. iOS 17.2, XCode 15.2.

On simulator first time the extension works and opens the main app, but on the second attempt the main app is not called. On simulator tested with iPad 6, iPad 9, iPad 10, iPad Air 6. On real iPad 6 does not work at all.